# Undead skeleton papercraft minitatures

Tags: miniatures, papercraft

Where can I find a digital, downloadable set of papercraft skeleton miniatures (or even just a single miniature)? Please note that by skeleton I mean the animated, undead monster (not a design aid for papercraft modeling). I don't mind paying a reasonable amount of money for good miniatures.

Comment: For a brief moment, I imagined a Papermancer - someone who raises paper constructs, moving origami of destruction. Sometimes I just love those titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arion Games](http://www.arion-games.com/paperminis.php) have a vast range of downloadable paper miniatures. Skeletons are catalogue number ARG068.

Comment: While these aren't the style I'd like (I'd prefer black-and-white with simple lines), they'll certainly do until I find something more to taste. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

My brother Kevin has made some incredible paper skeletons: You can get a flaming skeleton included with [some calendar dice](http://www.papercraftdungeon.com/d12-calendar-2013-includes-free-bonuses.html) (both free), or [a set of them for $1.99](http://www.papercraftdungeon.com/skeleton-scallywags-paper-miniatures.html).

Answer (score 2):

S. John Ross' Cumberland Fontworks publishes the [Sparks](http://www222.pair.com/sjohn/sparks.htm) series of paper miniatures -- the Dungeoneers set has *a* skeleton, anyway, among other critters and adventurers.  They're Truetype fonts, and as such scale nicely.  Based solely on my download of the freeware Sparks minis, the illustration quality is simple but fairly good.

Stipulated that these are printout standies, and not detailed, folded papercraft minis.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the link. I've seen Sparks before, but the whole font delivery is odd to me, and has never piqued my interested enough to try it out. Have you had good success with them?

Comment: They're nice when you want something more than a spare die or a poker chip — frankly at their best when I need a horde of identical minis and can't be arsed to spend my prep time drawing N variations on the theme of "zombie."  Handy, but not having them wouldn't change the way I game a'tall.

Comment: I prefer the outline font delivery. Good, crisp B&W, and I can scale them as I need. The Sparks fonts themselves are very nice because I can, using a page layout program (like Pages or Scribus) generate the figs, then do another layer with ID numbers. ANd I can print them out a suitable scale for use with 15mm minis or 20mm minis, as well as the 25/28mm scale.

Answer (score 1):

If you *only* want skeletons, this won't be much use to you, but Paizo (Pathfinder publisher) has a series of Paper Miniature sets.  Their instructions say to print them on cardstock, but I've found they do pretty well with just paper (I just slip a penny between the bases to weight them down so a gust of wind or table bump doesn't knock them out of position).  I'm personally using the Emerald Spire set, which has a set of six generic spearman skeletons early on, as well as a bone priest mini.  (I'm not that far through the set, though, because I'm only making them up a level in advance, and my group is only ready to start level 2.)